# Email query information in a trigger event

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger which whenever a user is inserting a specific value email the information (4 more columns) related to that value.

I don't know what is the best option, I tried:

Step #1: create a stored procedure when the trigger is in action

```
CREATE PROCEDURE NewVendorAlert
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @BODY NVARCHAR(800)

    SET @body = N'Hello,' + '<br>' + '<br>' +
    N'Please see the attachment of the new vendor information' + '<br>' + '<br>' +
    N'Sincerely,' + '<br>' + '<br>' +
    N'Process Improvement Department'


    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @profile_name = 'SQLMail',
            @recipients = 'gmolina@allenflavors.com',
            @subject = 'New Vendor Entered',
            @query = N'SELECT TOP 1  LTRIM(RTRIM(VENDORID)) AS [VENDOR ID],
              LTRIM(RTRIM(VENDNAME)) AS [VENDOR NAME],
                      CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(ADDRESS1)),'' '', LTRIM(RTRIM(ADDRESS2)), '' '', LTRIM(RTRIM(ADDRESS3)) ) AS [ADDRESS],
                      LTRIM(RTRIM(STATE)) [STATE],
                      LTRIM(RTRIM(COUNTRY)) [COUNTRY],
                      MAX(LTRIM(RTRIM(CREATDDT))) AS [DATE ENTERED]
        FROM [ALLEN].[dbo].[PM00200]
        GROUP BY VENDORID,CREATDDT, VENDNAME, ADDRESS1, ADDRESS2, ADDRESS3, STATE, COUNTRY
        ORDER BY CREATDDT DESC',
            @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
            @query_attachment_filename = 'New Vendor.csv',
            @query_result_separator = '       ',
            @query_result_no_padding = 1,
            @exclude_query_output = 1,
            @append_query_error = 0,
            @query_result_header = 1,
            @body = @body,
            @query_result_width = 32767,
            @importance = 'HIGH',
            @body_format = 'HTML'
        
        END
```

Step #2: create a trigger for that specific value is inserted, here I got an error when it comes to insert the value

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NewVendorInformation]
ON [dbo].[PM00200]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @VENDORID char(15); 
    SELECT @VENDORID = VENDORID from inserted --Then Only Value that I want
    EXEC NewVendorAlert -- STORED PROCEDURE
END
```

I tried other things, I would appreciate it if am I on the right path, or are there other options?

Thank you!

Comment: You're making a classic trigger 101 mistake, assuming that `inserted` only has a single record... when it could have 0-N. If this is truly the best way to handle it, then you need to loop through the records calling your SP once for each row in `Inserted`. And if you are receiving an error make sure you post it so we can see what it is.

Comment: Also: I'd **strongly recommend** not to do something like sending out an e-mail (which can take a fairly long time) from inside a trigger. The trigger runs in the context of the statement that caused it to fire, and extends that statement's transaction time, until the trigger is done. You should only do very little work in a trigger - and most definitely not call out to external services or send out e-mails ....

Comment: Well actually is not giving an error because it takes forever to execute when I insert a record. I just kill the Blocking_Session_ID. So, this is kind of tricky what you guys recommend when I insert that insert value email me the information on the Select Statement (inside the Stored Procedure). Because I did another code with the only trigger but I needed to declare other variables the problem was when I insert another value which it's not the value that I select is executing the trigger anyway. That's why I came to this option

Answer (score 1):

As has been commented you want to avoid doing anything slow within a trigger, and contacting an SMTP server can be very slow. The best solution when sending an email is required is to put an entry into a queue table and have a service process the queue and send the emails.

However there are times when you find yourself having to process the `Inserted` table RBAR in which case you need to loop through all the records, an example of how to do this follows.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[NewVendorInformation]
ON [dbo].[PM00200]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @VENDORID char(15); 

    SELECT VENDORID
    INTO #PM00200_Temp
    FROM Inserted
    GROUP BY VENDORID;

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #PM00200_Temp) BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @VENDORID = VENDORID FROM #PM00200_Temp;

        EXEC NewVendorAlert @VENDORID;

        DELETE FROM #PM00200_Temp WHERE VENDORID = @VENDORID;
    END;
END;
```

Comment: That's very helpful thank you @DaleK, I ran the trigger that you wrote but it threw me an error: `Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure NewVendorAlert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 24]
Procedure NewVendorAlert has no parameters and arguments were supplied.
The statement has been terminated.` That's weird because you declare a parameter on the Stored Procedure, and the same if I take the parameter out. Any thoughts?